# Using Gulp to launch MEAN Stack (frontend and backend)

Tags: angular, gulp, mean-stack

I have been learning to build mobiles apps using Angular 2. I never had the need for a backend until now. I am learning how to build a RestApi using express and MongoDB.

However, the documentation I find only shows how to run one or the other using gulp.

For example I been using Gulp-Connect when building frontend:

## FrontEnd:

```
// Start a server for project.
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
    root : '',
    livereload : true,
    fallback: 'index.html'
    });
});
```

While learning to make an API I used Gulp-nodmon:

## BackEnd

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    nodemon({
        script: 'app.js',
        ext: 'js',
        env: {
            PORT:8080
        },
        ignore: ['./node_modules/**']
    })
    .on('restart', function(){
        console.log('Restarting');
    });
});
```

My understanding is they both do the same thing, they launch the app on a local server using Node. My question is, how am I suppose to setup gulp so that it would launch both my frontend and backend? I used Yeomon generators to see how they do it but for the MEAN stack generators they tend to use NODE. I am sure certain this is fine but I have no clue how that is setup and am becoming more comfortable using gulp.

I may be completely misunderstanding the whole flow, anyone have some good explanations or pointers for me?

Comment: I would treat them as completely different services/projects. A nice thing about Single Page Apps is that you can decouple your backend completely from your front-end. I wouldn't even bother trying to set-up gulp to launch them at the same time, just launch them independently.

Comment: How do you manage your angular 2 ?? I mean transpilation part ??

Comment: As @shusson mention before I would split it into two speared projects. Angular 2 has no need for Gulp. Just use Angular-CLI. Build, serve all is included.
Your backend you can start and build also without gulp. Just use npm scripts. An example project could be this one here: https://github.com/sibelius/koa-passport-mongoose-graphql. It's based on koa but this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advice, i did explore it but something about it seemed off. The MEAN stack to me is a single code base approach for developing apps. I wanted to avoid having two Git repositories that are deployed to two heroku servers.

I did some more searching and ended up watching a 2 hours youtube video on mean stack development<->deployment.

It appears that express can deploy static html, which in turn would run my angular application.

So inside express you would write:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

and then in gulp you would either run that expressapp.js file or use NPM to launch it.